# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on Lucene Servlet

Tags: java, docker, lucene, full-text-search

Lucene Servlet is running on a docker openjdk:8 container with -Xmx512M parameter.

The **OutOfMemoryError** error is showing up at some search requests... seems to be randomly happening.

After occurrence of this error, no search can be done: docker container starts to take 200% cpu, and it queues requests.

When a search requests arrives, this is part of the code:

```
public String search(String indexName,...)  {
    :
    IndexSearcher searcher = createSearcher(indexName);
    :
    SortField[] sortFields = this.parseSortFields(indexName, sort);

    if (sortFields != null) {
        hits = searcher.search(q, pageSize, new Sort(sortFields));
    } else {
        hits = searcher.search(q, pageSize);
    }
    :
}

private IndexSearcher createSearcher(String indexName) throws Exception {
    return new IndexSearcher(createReader(indexName));
}

private IndexReader createReader(String indexName) throws Exception {
    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(INDEX_DIR + "/" + indexName));
    return DirectoryReader.open(dir);
}
```

More details:

- Lucene v6.6.0
- 500 concurrent users top (usually less)
- Indexed documents folder is taking up 678 MB

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone Usually that means 2 cores at 100%

Comment: I found out that 200% cpu it's actually a common error

Comment: So give it more than 512 Mb.

Comment: @IMustBeSomeone I ment the 200% cpu error on docker

Comment: @Andreas isn't it enough for less that 500 concurrent users?

Comment: @MartínVergara Apparently not.

Comment: I'll try it out, and tell you what the results are...